# Send Custom Error Response for HTTP default status codes

Tags: spring-boot, rest, http, exception, http-status-code-404

My Requirement is to override the response returned by the HTTP for Status codes like 404, 503 etc.

I had my fair share for searching about to override and send a custom error response for HTTP Status codes but all those answers are for the custom exception handling for what happens inside my resource. What i am looking for is a way to override the default response sent by HTTP in case of lets say 404 like

```
{
    "timestamp": "2024-03-05T17:15:57.389+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/v1/search"
}
```

For example: Lets assume my resource is like above **/api/v1/search** but in my postman i spell it wrong like **/api/v1/sear**

The response from HTTP will be like above. I want to override and return this HTTP response like

```
{
"code": "404",
"message": "Resource Not Found or check your spelling",
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot 2.2.5 404 page not found custom json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60960881/spring-boot-2-2-5-404-page-not-found-custom-json-response)

Answer (score 0):

You can use @RestControllerAdvice and define model for this exception.

For example:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public ExceptionHandlerResponse handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException exception,
                                                                    HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;

        return ExceptionHandlerResponse.builder()
                .code(httpStatus.value())
                .message(exception.getMessage())
                .build();
    }
```